# How to see what page along conversion funnel results in the most conversions in Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, conversions, reporting

I have a conversion configured for booking an appointment for a store. This works fine, however I am trying to break down which store page results in each conversion.

- Home > Store A > Book Appointment Page > Book Appointment Confirmation
- Home > Store B > Contact Page > Book Appointment Page > Book Appointment Confirmation
- Home > Store A > Store C > Book Appointment Page > Book Appointment Confirmation

Essentially I want to know how many of each store resulted in a conversion based on the user's path, with the last store page visited getting the attribution. Is there any way that I can report on this out of the box?

Comment: What do you want the report to show when they visit two different stores like your third example where it has both store A and store C?

Comment: Ideally just the last "store" page visited before a conversion. Any prior store pages along the path can be ignored.